# psycopg2: how to pass VARIADIC ARGS?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to call the function `json_extract_path` which accepts variadic arguments. Does psycopg2 support queries of the form `f(%s, %s, ...)`, which would accept a variable number of parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL format answer works, but I think it's far more complicated than you need.  Just add the VARIADIC keyword and send your arguments as a list.  Using the example from json_extract_path:

```
>>> cur.execute('''SELECT json_extract_path('{"f2":{"f3":1},"f4":{"f5":99,"f6":"foo"}}', VARIADIC %s)''', [['f4', 'f6']])
>>> cur.fetchall()
[('foo',)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is... mostly no, but kinda yes.

psycopg2 has no placeholder for variable arguments, AFAIK it doesn't parse the "format string" at all so it has no idea about *context of use*, it will just dumbly apply "data" escaping and formatting rules to individual parameters, so you need to create an SQL / format string with the correct number of placeholders, then flatten your sequence as "top-level" parameters.

*However* psycopg2 2.7 added a [`psycopg2.sql`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module which assists with "dynamic" SQL compositions. What you'd do here is use those facilities to generate your query e.g.

```py
path = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cursor.execute(
    sql.SQL('select json_extract_path(col, {}) from table').format(
        sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Placeholder() * len(path))
    ),
    [*path]
)
```

(nb: code untested)

- SQL.format validates that the formatted parameters are `Composable`, so they have been marked a safe explicitly
- `sql.Placeholder()` is a `Composable` version of `%s` (it can take an optional name), as you can see it also supports "splatting" specifically for the case where you have a variable number of parameters e.g. `VALUES` enumeration or function calls
- `SQL.join` is a `Composable` version of `str.join`
- then you can just pass in your parameters normally, splatting your sequences to "flatten" them

Comment: Essentially, this module does "injection-safe" string concatenation? or something more too?

Comment: It doesn't quite *do* injection-safe variadics, but it aims to help with creating "dynamic" SQL queries in general in a somewhat safe manner (safer than string concatenation at least).